# Spring boot actuator health check in Openshift/Kubernetes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, openshift, spring-boot-actuator

We have a situation where we have an abundance of Spring boot applications running in containers (on OpenShift) that access centralized infrastructure (external to the pod) such as databases, queues, etc.

If a piece of central infrastructure is down, the health check returns "unhealthy" (rightfully so). The problem is that the liveliness check sees this, and restarts the pod (the readiness check then sees it's down too, so won't start the app). This is fine when only a few are available, but if many (potentially hundreds) of applications are using this, it forces restarts on all of them (crash loop).

I understand that central infrastructure being down is a bad thing. It "should" never happen. But... if it does (Murphy's law), it throws containers into a frenzy. Just seems like we're either doing something wrong, or we should reconfigure something.

A couple questions:

- If you are forced to use centralized infrastructure from a Spring boot app running in a container on OpenShift/Kubernetes, should all actuator checks still be enabled for backend? (bouncing the container really won't fix the backend being down anyway)
- Should the /actuator/health endpoint be set for both the liveliness probe and the readiness probe?
- What common settings do folk use for the readiness/liveliness probe in a spring boot app? (timeouts/interval/etc).

Answer (score 2):

1. Using actuator checks for liveness/readiness is the de-facto way to check for healthy app in Spring Boot Pod. Your application, once up, should ideally not go down or become unhealthy if a central piece, such as DB or Queueing service goes down , ideally you should add some sort of a resiliency which will either connect to alternate DR site or wait for certain time period for central service to come back up and app to reconnect. This is more of a technical failure on backend side causing a functional failure of your Application after it was started up cleanly.
2. Yes , both liveness and readiness is required as they both serve different purposes. Read [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/)
3. In one of my previous projects, the settings used for readiness was around 30 seconds and liveness at around 90, but to be honest this is completely dependent on your application , if your app takes 1 minute to start , that is what your readiness time should be configured at , and your liveness should factor in the same along with any time required for making failover switch of your backend services.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you know how you’d globally configure backend connections to retry in spring boot? It’d somehow have to let the health check succeed, or the health check timeout in liveliness probe would kick in while waiting for it to retry until it comes back up.

Comment: You need to apply a High Availability DB or apply Circuit Breaker pattern. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45800582/primary-secondary-failover-datasource-in-spring-boot/51067888) for more details