# Switch from master to slave DB by Spring boot code

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, groovy, load-balancing

We have a requirement to switch databases when one is down like if the master is down application should work on the slave.

This was a link which we first checked [Primary/Secondary failover DataSource in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45800582/primary-secondary-failover-datasource-in-spring-boot), which took us to [Using HA-JDBC with Spring Boot](https://dzone.com/articles/using-ha-jdbc-with-spring-boot), which we doubt is a valid Java code

Then we came upon this link [A complete guide to setting up Master and Slave (or multiple) Datasources in Spring](https://medium.com/swlh/a-complete-guide-to-setting-up-multiple-datasources-in-spring-8296d4ff0935), but here problem is that we can read and write in Master but in Slave, we can only read!

Finally, we came to know about **Data base load balancing services** like *HAProxy*, *MariaDB MaxScale*, *Scalable Cluster for MySQL* etc. So in our Spring boot application, we just need to configure the URL of the particular load balancing service.

So our question is whether there is any approach by which we can achieve the same with just coding in Spring Boot or we need to use those load balancing services?

**Updates after converting the Groovy code to Java**

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="hajdbc")
@ConditionalOnClass({Driver.class}) //
@Configuration
public class HaJdbcConfiguration {

    private List<DriverDatabase> driverDatabases;
    private String clusterName = "default";
    private String cronExpression = "0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *";
    private String defaultSynchronizationStrategy = "full";
    private String stateManagerUrl;
    private String stateManagerUser;
    private String stateManagerPassword;
    private boolean identityColumnDetectionEnabled = true;
    private boolean sequenceDetectionEnabled = true;

    @PostConstruct
    public void register() {

        DriverDatabaseClusterConfiguration config = new DriverDatabaseClusterConfiguration();
        config.setDatabases(driverDatabases);
        config.setDatabaseMetaDataCacheFactory(new SimpleDatabaseMetaDataCacheFactory());
        config.setBalancerFactory(new SimpleBalancerFactory());

        SQLStateManagerFactory sqlStateManagerFactory = new SQLStateManagerFactory();
        sqlStateManagerFactory.setUrlPattern(stateManagerUrl);
        sqlStateManagerFactory.setUser(stateManagerUser);
        sqlStateManagerFactory.setPassword(stateManagerPassword);
        config.setStateManagerFactory(sqlStateManagerFactory);

        FullSynchronizationStrategy syncStartegy = new FullSynchronizationStrategy();
        Map<String, SynchronizationStrategy> strategyMap = new HashMap<String, SynchronizationStrategy>();
        strategyMap.put(syncStartegy.getId(), syncStartegy);
        config.setSynchronizationStrategyMap(strategyMap);

        config.setDefaultSynchronizationStrategy(defaultSynchronizationStrategy);
        config.setIdentityColumnDetectionEnabled(identityColumnDetectionEnabled);
        config.setSequenceDetectionEnabled(sequenceDetectionEnabled);
        config.setAutoActivationExpression(new CronExpression(cronExpression));

        Driver.setConfigurationFactory(clusterName,
                new SimpleDatabaseClusterConfigurationFactory<Driver, DriverDatabase>(config));
    }
}
```

We tried converting the Groovy code to Java as **@M. Deinum** suggested, but still its not complete.

1. In the Groovy code, a line is specified as `@ConditionalOnClass(Driver)` which we changed to `@ConditionalOnClass({Driver.class})`. We are still not sure it's right.
2. What would be the return type of the method `def register() {` in Groovy, in Java we kept it void.
3. List of Driver Databases is `null` and is set to the configuration, the private fields `stateManagerUrl`, `stateManagerUser` and `stateManagerPassword` are also null and set to a factory, maybe this will be read from the properties file.
4. The main issue is the last line, this is the Groovy code

   `Driver.setConfigurationFactory(clusterName, new SimpleDatabaseClusterConfigurationFactory<java.sql.Driver, DriverDatabase>(config));`

But in Java we need a reference to call the `setConfigurationFactory` method, what should be the reference type?

Comment: The code [here](https://dzone.com/articles/using-ha-jdbc-with-spring-boot) is in Groovy (so not java) but should be easily transfered to Java (almost one on one). However you are probably better of using an external solution (the loadbalancing stuff) then shoehorning this into your application.

Comment: I don't know the driver, I only mentioned the code is in Groovy. Instead of blindly trying to convert the code I strongly suggest a read of the documentation for the library on how to configure things in Java (and maybe there is another Spring Boot tutorial which is using java).